# How to add package jade-handlebars

Tags: meteor, pug, meteorite

I am just a newbie in meteor and meteorite. I create a new project by `mrt create my-app --branch devel`. I have install meteorite by `$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` now when I add the package `mrt add bootstrap` the packages successfully added but on doing `mrt add jade-handlers`  it wont show anything(either error or sucess) so how can I add the jade-handlerbars packages in my meteor project??

I am using node --version 0.10.11
meteorite --version 0.6.5
release 0.6.4

Thank You in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your smart.json is pointing at the tag on that package, rather than the git repo itself. (The last update to the package did not include a version bump, so the version of the package you get just by `mrt add`ing it is outdated.)

Try putting this in your smart.json:

```
"jade-handlebars": {
  "git": "https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars.git"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo I guess?

`mrt add jade-handlebars` instead of `mrt add jade-handlers`

Answer (score 0):

I also just figure it out that you can add the packages from the atmosphere by

```
mrt add <package> --repoPort=443
```